# table css with groups in different color

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

My table looks like below:

```
Grade   Sign    StudentGrade
6       +       1
6               0
6       -       0
5       +       0
5               0
5       -       0
4       +       0
4               0
4       -       1
3       +       0
3               1
3       -       0
2       +       1
2               0
2       -       0
1       +       0
1               1
1       -       0
```

My html table looks like

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of gradeList;">
    <td colspan="3" class="labelStyle" style="text-align:center">{{item.grade}}</td>
    <td colspan="3" class="labelStyle" style="text-align:center" *ngIf="item.sign == 0"></td>
    <td colspan="3" class="labelStyle" style="text-align:center" *ngIf="item.sign == 1">+</td>
    <td colspan="3" class="labelStyle" style="text-align:center" *ngIf="item.sign < 0">-</td>
    <td colspan="2" class="labelStyle" style="text-align:center">{{item.studentGrade}}</td>
</tr>
```

I want to add colors to my tr in such a way 1st 3 rows with grade 6 is light grey and next 3 for grader 5 default color and next 3 for grade 4 grey and so on. How can I do this dynamically?

Comment: have you tried `:nth-child()` with a `n-var` already?

Comment: @tacoshy no i did not know how to try for 3 rows. I was able to get an example for alternate rows though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one approach is the use of `:nth-child()` selector in combination with the `n-variable`. use `6n` like in the sample below.

```css
tr:nth-child(6n+2),
tr:nth-child(6n+3),
tr:nth-child(6n+4) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Grade</td>
    <td>Sign</td>
    <td>Student Grade</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>+</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>-</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>+</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>-</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>+</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>-</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>+</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>-</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>+</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>-</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>+</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>-</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to colour the table row background based on cell content, you need to use JavaScript to do that.

```js
let table = document.getElementById("grades-table");
let gradeColors = {
  '1': '#99f',
  '2': '#aaf',
  '3': '#bbf',
  '4': '#ccf',
  '5': '#ddf',
  '6': '#eef'
};
for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
   //iterate through rows
   col = row.cells[0];
   row.style.backgroundColor = gradeColors[col.textContent];
}
```

```css
table {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th {
  background: aliceblue;
  color: darkblue;
}
td, th {
  text-align: center;
  padding: .5em;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<table id="grades-table">
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Grade</th><th>Sign</th><th>StudentGrade</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>6</td><td>+</td><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>6</td><td> </td><td>0</td></tr>
        <tr><td>6</td><td>-</td><td>0</td></tr>
        <tr><td>5</td><td>+</td><td>0</td></tr>
        <tr><td>5</td><td> </td><td>0</td></tr>
        <tr><td>5</td><td>-</td><td>0</td></tr>
        <tr><td>4</td><td>+</td><td>0</td></tr>
        <tr><td>4</td><td> </td><td>0</td></tr>
        <tr><td>4</td><td>-</td><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>3</td><td>+</td><td>0</td></tr>
        <tr><td>3</td><td> </td><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>3</td><td>-</td><td>0</td></tr>
        <tr><td>2</td><td>+</td><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>2</td><td> </td><td>0</td></tr>
        <tr><td>2</td><td>-</td><td>0</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td><td>+</td><td>0</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td><td> </td><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td><td>-</td><td>0</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```